# How to provide a limit for USER_ID/likes request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app that checks if a user already likes my fb-page, but it stopped working because of the latest Facebook update (oct 13 13): You are not providing a limit when requesting user_id/likes, etc...

This is what I'm doing...

```
$likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/".$page);
$user = $facebook->api('/me');
$first = $user["first_name"];
```

Facebook says:
/USER_ID/likes default update
Currently the API returns all likes by default. After the migration, fetching a user's likes via the Graph API will return 25 results at a time. We've added pagination to the results so you can page through to all of a user's likes.

So SINCE there is pagination now, will i have to requrite the whole thing. Or can i just add limit=1000 somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be the need for pagination if you're checking if the user already likes your page.

From [Facebook User Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes)

> You can check if a User likes a specific page by issuing an HTTP GET to /PROFILE_ID/likes/PAGE_ID. This requires the user_likes (current user) or friends_likes (current user's friend) permission.

The issue most likely lies with your $page variable, if you send a get request with the empty variable you'll solely be calling

> /me/likes/

which will return all of the user's likes. Try echoing your $page variable separately to see if it is set correctly.